# GLIBC_2.9 missing

Tags: qt, embedded, shared-libraries, embedded-linux, armv7

I am working in embedded system domain and i was trying to cross-compile a QT- program for the ARMv7 platform.

I am using the following cross-compiler ---

" angstrom-2011.03-x86_64-linux-armv7a-linux-gnueabi-toolchain-qte-4.6.3.tar "

I had all the shared libraries required by the program inside /usr/lib folder ( I am using Angstrom-linux in my target platform ) so i guess there is no need to give path of my shared libraries to the loader. But still it is showing some error that some of the shared libraries require  GLIBC_2.9 ( "error : GLIBC_2.9 not found" ). I don't have a gcc compiler for my target platform so i am cross-compiling my programs, is that the reason ???????????

Comment: Where is your cross-compuler located?

Comment: Then "so i guess there is no need to give path of my shared libraries to the loader." is wrong. You do need to pass the /usr/local/.../lib to the LIBS variable in the qmake file.

Comment: It's in the home directory on my PC  " ~/usr/local/angstrom/arm/bin ".All my shared libraries are in "~/usr/local/angstrom/arm/arm-angstrom-linux-gnueabi/usr/lib". I am using a 64-bit Linux system running on x86 platform.

Comment: Thanks... let me try it

Comment: Looks like this tool requires older version of glibc than you have on your system.

Comment: @LaszloPapp : sorry for not replying because i got very busy in some other work. I haven't tried the solution yet, but i will inform u about the same. Thanks for your kind advice

Comment: Is this still unresolved one year later??

Answer (score 0):

This is what you should do in a qmake based project for cross-compiling in your scenario:

```
qmake -r -spec linux-arm-gnueabi-g++
```

and the qmake project file should contain this:

```
LIBS += /usr/local/.../lib # path to your embedded target libraries
```

Note that you may also need to set up the following variable, too, for having the includes right:

```
INCLUDEPATH += /usr/local/.../include # path to your embedded target headers
```